# Consider defining a bean of type 'reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using SpringBoot2, Spring5 in my Java micro service application. I have required dependencies including the Scheduler. Build is fine without any compilation error but during run time, I'm getting below error in `PooledAsyncRunner`:-

> ***************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>   *************************** Description: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.connector.async.core.PooledAsyncRunner required a bean of type
>   'reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler' that could not be found. Action:
>   Consider defining a bean of type 'reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler' in
>   your configuration.

```
@Service
    public class PooledAsyncRunner implements AsyncRunner {

  private final Scheduler scheduler;

  @Autowired
  public PooledAsyncRunner(Scheduler scheduler) {
    this.scheduler = scheduler;
  }
}
```

Below is spring main application file where I have explicitly annotated auto-configuration:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MarketApplication {
}
```

I have reactor-core dependency as well in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Why is the scheduler final?

Comment: i tried removing final as well but still the same result.

Comment: @horatius Coz he initializes in constructor ?

Comment: Did you define a bean of type reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler in your configuration? I would add a '@Bean' public Scheduler GetScheduler() {….} in a class with '@Configuration' annotation and then check.

Comment: You have not enabled scheduling. Did u include elsewhere? `@EnableScheduling`

Comment: thanks everyone...@horatius currently there is no confirguation class..im adding it by myself. just a quick question here... getSchedular() I should return its new object, right?

Comment: what's that asyncrunner interface? Why does it need a reactor scheduler to work? Please add more context to your question.

Comment: @VinodKumar Yes you just return a new Scheduler(). Don't know the constructor off the top of my head, but you can look at javadocs to see which constructor is most suitable for you.

Comment: @VinodKumar Also, you should try what Karthik R suggested first. If that doesn't work, only then you use my solution.

Comment: @KarthikR That's a valid answer. You should post it as an answer.